# IIS performance improvements

Tags: performance, iis

What can be done to improve performance in IIS? When I deploy my webapplication to my local IIS machine it goes much slower than when I run the solution in visual studio without debugging. The difference is remarkable, like double as fast.

Comment: Have you checked to see if you are still running the application as Debug in the web.config file?

Comment: yes i have, i even deleted all pdb files to be sure he didn't use them

Answer (score 0):

Some things I can think of -

1. Check your processor usage and memory usage - this can be extremely important.
2. check if Gzip compression is enabled - enabling this on an already overloaded CPU can further degrade performance. However over network this will save you bandwidth, so its a good option to enable when processor is not overloaded
3. Is this on the same machine or different machines? If your build machine is less capable than your development machine (which is sometimes the case) that could add to the problem

Also have you considered the initial compile time for the websites? At least the first page load in local IIS will be somewhat slower because of the initial compilation that takes place on request of the page. In Visual studio, you will see this separately as a build step and this could also create an illusion of VS dev server being faster than IIS.

Comment: thx for your comments.
1)CPU and memory are in acceptable levels
2)Gzip compression was enabled. Disabling however did not improve performance
3)They are on the same machine
4)i tested the load time with several reloads to make sure eveything is loaded

Comment: Could you try moving to a separate machine which does not have heavy tools such as VS installed? Just to be sure - a build machine is cleaner and generally more performant, anything could be slowing IIS down.